# Memory game code quality

Tags: javascript, beginner, classes

I am making an incremental-memory-game similar to this https://www.crazygames.com/game/incremental-memory

I am not very satisfied of how spaghetti this code is. I am trying to learn to improve my code quality, and make it as professional as it should, I hope if you an try to restructure this code to make it very inovative and clear to read.

For now, I am making only the first level of the game (2 hearts, level 1)

This is a code snippet:

````
export default class Board {
  #cells;
  #hearts;
  constructor(hearts) {
    this.#hearts = hearts;
    this.#cells = Array(9).fill(false);
    // const randomIndexes = this.getRandomCellIndex();
    // this.#cells = randomIndexes;
  }

  getRandomCellIndex() {
    const arr = Array(9).fill(false);
    const indexes = new Set();
    while (indexes.size < 3) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
      indexes.add(randomIndex);
    }
    for (const index of indexes) {
      arr[index] = true;
    }
    return arr;
  }
  setAttributeCells() {
    const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
    this.#cells = this.getRandomCellIndex();
    this.#cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
      if (cell === true) {
        const gridItem = gridItems[index];
        gridItem.setAttribute("data-memory", "true");

        setTimeout(() => {
          gridItem.removeAttribute("data-memory");
        }, 400);
      }
    });
  }
  get cells() {
    return this.#cells;
  }
  get hearts() {
    return this.#hearts;
  }
  addClickEventHandlers() {
    let trueCount = 0;
    let clickCount = 0;

    const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");

    gridItems.forEach((button, index) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        clickCount++;

        if (clickCount <= 3) {
          if (this.#cells[index]) {
            this.setTile(button, true);
            trueCount++;
          } else this.setTile(button, false);
        } else return;

        if (trueCount === 3) {
          // Display the win message
          console.log("You win!");
        } else if (clickCount === 3 && trueCount < 3) {
          this.#hearts--;
          this.setHearts();
        }
      });
    });
  }
  setTile(button, boolean) {
    button.setAttribute("data-memory", boolean);
  }
  discardTile(button, boolean) {
    button.removeAttribute("data-memory", boolean);
  }
  setCoundownTimer() {
    let countdownTime = 1;

    // Set the initial width of the countdown div to 100%
    const countdownElement = document.querySelector(".countdown");
    console.log(countdownElement);
    const containerWidth = countdownElement.parentElement.clientWidth; // Get the width of the countdown container

    // Calculate the width decrease per second
    const widthDecrease = containerWidth / countdownTime;
    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
      // Decrease the countdown time by 1 second
      countdownTime--;

      // Calculate the new width of the countdown div
      const newWidth = countdownElement.clientWidth - widthDecrease;
      countdownElement.style.width = newWidth + "px";
      console.log(countdownTime);
      // If the countdown reaches zero, display a message
      if (countdownTime === 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        countdownElement.style.width = "0"; // Set width to 0 when countdown is over
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  setHearts() {
    const heartsContainer = document.querySelector(".hearts");

    while (heartsContainer.firstChild) {
      heartsContainer.removeChild(heartsContainer.firstChild);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.#hearts; i++) {
      // Create a new SVG element
      let svgElement = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "svg"
      );

      // Set the attributes of the SVG element
      svgElement.setAttribute("class", "heartSvg");
      svgElement.setAttribute("width", "32");
      svgElement.setAttribute("clip-rule", "evenodd");
      svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "#fff4f4");
      svgElement.setAttribute("fill-rule", "evenodd");
      svgElement.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");
      svgElement.setAttribute("stroke-miterlimit", "2");
      svgElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
      svgElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

      // Create the path element
      let pathElement = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "path"
      );

      // Set the attributes of the path element
      pathElement.setAttribute(
        "d",
        "m12 5.72c-2.624-4.517-10-3.198-10 2.461 0 3.725 4.345 7.727 9.303 12.54.194.189.446.283.697.283s.503-.094.697-.283c4.977-4.831 9.303-8.814 9.303-12.54 0-5.678-7.396-6.944-10-2.461z"
      );
      pathElement.setAttribute("fill-rule", "nonzero");

      // Append the path element to the SVG element
      svgElement.appendChild(pathElement);

      // Append the SVG element to the hearts container
      heartsContainer.appendChild(svgElement);
    }
  }
}
const boardArr = new Board(1);

boardArr.setAttributeCells();
boardArr.addClickEventHandlers();
boardArr.setCoundownTimer();
boardArr.setHearts();
```
````